# Resharper 8.2 with Zen or Emmet

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, emmet, zen

I'm using VS 2013 Ultimate with Resharper 8.2. I had previously installed an Emmet plug-in for VS 2013 and now that works in a sort of temperamental way (many Zen abbreviations don't expand or don't expand as expected).

My priority is to have VS 2013 working with Resharper 8.2 even if that means not using Zen coding. There is a Resharper PowerToy for Resharper 6 and VS 2010 but I've not seen any updates to that.

Is anybody successfully using a Zen/Emmet plug-in with Resharper 8.2 in VS 2013 and, if so, which tool are you using?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The ReSharper SDK comes with a sample that supports Zen Coding. There's no binary distribution right now, although it should still work, and you should be able to build the plugin if you wish.

Since it's based on the old Python codebase, and requires the DLR to run, I'm retiring the sample from the next release of the SDK. I'm working on a replacement Emmet extension, that will be on github, and also released to the ReSharper extension gallery. Unfortunately, I don't have a timescale. Sorry to not have better news...

Comment: Thank you for the update. ReSharper aside, I have an Emmet plug-in that works well without ReShaper. It expands Zen expressions after hitting the Tab key. With ReSharper installed, that expansion doesn't happen (or at least not reliably). Is there a way to prevent whatever interference is occurring so that I can continue to be ReSharper active while also using the Emmet plug-in?